# Is CAPTCHA a contrived acronym?

Tags: acronyms

While I understand why [*USA PATRIOT*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA_PATRIOT_Act) is a contrived acronym, I don't understand if *CAPTCHA* should be considered a contrived acronym.

Is *CAPTCHA* a contrived acronym? Why?

Comment: It's a rare acronym that isn't contrived.

Comment: @mickeyf: How on earth can you say that? Are you seriously suggesting it would have been called *Completely Automated Public Turing Test To Tell Computers and Humans Apart* if the initial letters (ignoring a few repeated T's) hadn't happened to spell out a homonym of a word closely associated with the purpose of the system?

Comment: Oh, I thought the CA part stood for _completely annoying_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*CAPTCHA* is homophonous to *capture*, and thus it is a contrived acronym, as described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA). As to why it is a contrived acronym, it is the goal of the *CAPTCHA* system to *capture* bots trying to pass as human beings, in order to prevent them from doing certain actions.

Comment: Homophonous in England.  But Carnegie Mellon is in the US.

Comment: @GEdgar Well, in some parts of the US, too. For instance Boston, Long Island, and many southern areas.

Comment: I always thought they first decided on CAPTCHA and then thought up a funny trail of words to suit the purpose into the full form!

Answer (score 7):

From [The  Official CAPTCHA Site](http://www.captcha.net/)

> The term CAPTCHA (for Completely
>   Automated Public Turing Test To Tell
>   Computers and Humans Apart) was coined
>   in 2000 by Luis von Ahn, Manuel Blum,
>   Nicholas Hopper and John Langford of
>   Carnegie Mellon University.

Since  CAPTCHA it is pronounced like a normal word it is an acronym, and not an initialism like e.g. IBM.

To answer the question:

From [Acronym and initialism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym_and_initialism)

> A contrived acronym is one
>   deliberately designed to be especially
>   apt for the thing being named (by
>   having a dual meaning or by borrowing
>   the positive connotations of an
>   existing word).[citation needed] Some
>   examples of contrived acronyms are USA
>   PATRIOT, CAN SPAM, CAPTCHA and ACT UP.

Comment: There was a device for finding lost sheep called BO PEEP.